# Jekyll and Json files for data - How to retrieve the right data in a general way?

Tags: json, jekyll

Suppose to have a json with this format:

```
{
    "components":[
        {
            "id": "c3-1",
            "type":"charts",
            "component":"ChartC3Line",
            "description":"Chart with round",
            "picture": "/assets/img/components/chartc3-round.png",
            "project": "yyy",
            "date": "06-07-2015",
            "dateupdate": "08-07-2015",
            "status":" production"
        },

        {
            "id": "c3-2",
            "type":"charts",
            "component":"ChartC3Date",
            "description":"Chart with Date",
            "picture": "/assets/img/components/chartc3-withdate.png
id: c3-2",
            "date": "06-07-2015",
            "project": "xxx",
            "dateupdate": "08-07-2015",
            "status":" production"
        }]

}
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve informations about the second object with id: c3-2.

Premise:

- I don't want to get it by index;

How can I get it by value ? by id for example.
Surely I have to change the structure of my json file.

How will you change it ?
For now I'm able to get the right value by index:

```
{% assign comp = site.data.components.components[1] %}
                    {{ comp.component }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your _data/components.json like this :

```
{
    "c3-1" : {
            "type":"charts",
            "component":"ChartC3Line",
            "description":"Chart with round"
    },
    "c3-2" : {
            "type":"charts",
            "component":"ChartC3Date",
            "description":"Chart with Date"
    }
}
```

You can now get an element by his id : `{{ site.data.components["c3-1"] }}`.

Comment: I'm trying to use {{ site.data.components["c3-1"].type }} but nothing appears!

Comment: For me `{{ site.data.components["c3-1"].type }}` works. Did you have a githuv repository to test ?